# Linked tables are sometimes locked MS Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two MS Access files (.mdb) one is called "A" and the second one is called "B".
A contains the database tables and B is read only and contains reports. B also contains Tables and are linked to the tables of A.
When I run a report from B, the linked tables are locked and give me nothing. 
Is there any solution for that?
Thanks,

Comment: It sounds like you or someone else has an exclusive file lock on "A". If "A" is open in MSAccess, close that instance of access and try your reports again.  If that fails, you will have to find out who has the file exclusively locked.

Comment: yes, because all the databases are shared. is there anyway we can guarantee to prevent the Locking using VBA code? sorry I am new to VBA.

Comment: When you say read-only, do you mean that the directory that contains the files is read only? This often causes problems with Access, because of the locking file, (ldb). If a user with read-only permissions opens a database, other users cannot gain access, because of the lock file. It cannot be fixed with VBA.

Comment: The question is quite confusingly worded. When you say "B contains tables and are linked to the tables of A" do you mean B has its own local tables plus links to the tables in A, or do you mean that all the tables in B are linked tables pointing to A? When you say "when I run a report from B" do you mean you open B and run the reports? Or are you using Application.Run to open the reports in B from A?

Answer (score 1):

Further to Remous's comment, if you have set up B.mdb as read only to keep your users from changing the reports, you can accomplish the same thing by making an MDE out of B.mdb. It's effectively compiling the existing MDB and turns off editing forms, reports, etc. Data can change, and I think macros can be imported/exported - but otherwise its pretty bullet resistant.

You can do that by going to:  Tools -> Database Utilities -> Make MDE

Comment: Making an MDE/ACCDE makes the design of all code-bearing objects read-only. This means that it has no effect on tables, queries and macros, none of which are code-bearing. It locks forms, reports and modules.